# In Laravel 5.3, auth::loginUsingId() is giving an undefined error

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to change the authenticated user server-side. I'm trying to use:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```

This should work from everything I've read but I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId()
```

I get the same error with:

```
Auth::login();
```

It should be noted that I'm using the namespace "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth" and that Auth::user(); return the expected authenticated user.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `RequestGuard` not `SessionGuard`. This guard does not have those methods as there is no such concept as 'logging' in with it.

The Auth docs are for the default guard `web`, `SessionGuard`. Which is something you can log into because there is state on the server side to track this. This is what all the auth scaffold is for.

`RequestGuard` is something you have to define the callback for how you want to authenticate the user for each request.

Since `RequestGuard` isn't going to give you persistence and you are only looking to set a user on a guard for the current reqeuest you can call `setUser` (takes an Authenticatable[interface] instance)  which all the guards have as a method for setting a user instance on a guard.

Comment: I see but Auth::user() is returning the currently authenticated user. Is there no way to change the authenticated user?

Comment: Did you look at that guard class and see what methods it has?

Comment: It should be noted that I had this working. I was able to succesfully call loginUsingId and it changed the return of Auth:User(). However, something must have changed as it no longer works and is returning the undefined error. So I'm really focused on getting this method to work. What I don't understand is according to the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) I have the right namespace and I'm using the correct method name. So what gives? Not giving the  expected result would be one thing but it shouldn't return undefined.

Comment: again, its not the SesionGuard, its RequestGuard .. its using a different guard than the defualt which means someone changed the default guard or something changed it during the lifecycle

Comment: Okay, I appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction. I think it's an issue with our guard implementation. Lastly, the setUser method on RequestGuard should do what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I tested that "setUser" method will work in this situation (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Guard.php). If you can add that to your response I'll give you the accepted answer.